# Don't play iMessage notification sound on Mac if read on iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, messages, notifications

I'm happily receiving and sending iMessages on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.3) and iPhone 4S (iOS 8.3).

When I've read a message on one device it notifies about receival (after 30 seconds or so) on the other device but doesn't play the sound, which would be really annoying.

Strangely enough this is not the case for my siblings and friends. They get the notification—with sound—on every device at the same time. This is quite annoying but I can't find anywhere to change the behaviour.

Anybody know how to control this?

Comment: if they haven't used any device recently it should notify on all, but if it thinks you are actively using a device that device will get priority.

Comment: It may be due to 'speed' of connectivity - not connection, but time differential between your ISP & mobile. If I pick up on Mac, my phone drops the notification immediately; you can test by tapping Home but not unlocking, then switch to Messages on Mac. If i don't swap to Messages within maybe 15s to acknowledge, the phone 'dings'. If I unlock the phone to read, the blue dot on Messages disappears.. though slightly slower, maybe 5s.

Comment: That is how it works for me as well and how I think it should work, but not due to network lag, it's rather the device getting higher priority as @Tyson says (gladly :).